# How to save multiple dictionaries to hdf5 and combine information for common keys from different dictionaries?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

Briefly, I'm interested is there any efficient way to save multiple dictionaries with common keys into hdf5 file.

Perhaps I have N dictionaries with the following structure (I will use 2 dicts in the below example):

```
sample_1 = {'gene1_gene1': 1,
            'gene1_gene2': -0.385,
            'gene1_gene3': 0.25,
            'gene2_gene2': 1,
            'gene2_gene3': 0.004,
            'gene3_gene3': 1
           }
sample_2 = {'gene1_gene1': 1,
            'gene1_gene2': -0.0035,
            'gene1_gene4': 0.0421,
            'gene2_gene2': 1,
            'gene2_gene4': -0.0783,
            'gene4_gene4': 1
           }
```

Each dictionary contains M keys. Some keys are common for multiple dictionaries (like `gene1_gene2`), some keys are unique (like both `gene2_gene3` and `gene2_gene4`).
I want to save each dictionary to the one hdf5 file with the structure like this one:

```
{
    'gene1_gene2': {
         'sample_1': -0.385,
         'sample_2': -0.0035,
         ....
    }
    ....
}
```

So the file must contain both values for each key and the corresponding sample names.

After that, I want to extract both sample names and values from hdf5 file using target `geneX_geneY` pairs.

To do it, I write this code:

```
with h5py.File("out_file.hdf5", 'a') as f:
    for gene_pair, cor_val in sample_N.items():
        try:
            grp = f.create_group(gene_pair)
            grp.create_dataset('data', (0,), maxshape=(None,), dtype=h5py.string_dtype(encoding='ascii'),
                               compression="gzip", compression_opts=9)
            grp.create_dataset('cor', (0,), maxshape=(None,), dtype='f4', compression="gzip", compression_opts=9)
            data = f[gene_pair]['data']
            cor = f[gene_pair]['cor']
            cor.resize(cor.shape[0] + 1, axis=0)
            cor[-1] = cor_val
            data.resize(data.shape[0] + 1, axis=0)
            data[-1] = 'sample_N'
        except:
            data = f[gene_pair]['data']
            cor = f[gene_pair]['cor']
            cor.resize(cor.shape[0] + 1, axis=0)
            cor[-1] = cor_val
            data.resize(data.shape[0] + 1, axis=0)
            data[-1] = 'sample_N'
```

Briefly, code creates groups corresponding to `geneX_geneY` key and save both the value (`f[gene_pair]['cor']`) and the dataset name (`f[gene_pair]['data']`) to corresponding datasets with numpy arrays.

I'm interested, is there any efficient way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'efficient'?  Are you hoping for the mythical `numpy` vectorized solution.  Python dictionaries can't be "vectorized".  Values are accessed one by one (unless you convert them to lists with `items()`).  Likewise `h5py` groups are dictionary-like.  It's the `h5py` datasets that are arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, HDF5/h5py uses NumPy array structures and doesn't support dictionaries. Frankly, I think arrays are far superior to dictionaries for managing this kind of data. (Personally, I would NOT store the gene_pair data in dictionaries...way to messy to load and unload...but that's just me.)

There is no need to create a `gene_pair` group with separate datasets for `cor` and `data`. In fact, your method complicates the schema, requiring access to 2 different datasets to get `cor` and `data`. You can do it all in a single dataset/table for each `gene_pair` (equivalent to a NumPy record array). There are a lot of ways to do this. If you can change the gene_pair data structure upstream of this process, I would highly recommend a NumPy record array. It has a natural mapping to HDF5/h5py datasets, and creating them is a one step process. If you can't (or don't want) to do that, I have 3 suggestions.

Note: Code to create the sample_N dictionary is the same for all methods and provided at the end.

Also, I followed your example and created each dataset/table as an expandable dataset with zero rows initially, adding one row at a time. This is OK for small data samples, but reallocating large datasets will become slow if you have millions of rows. If you plan to add a lot of data, I suggest a different approach. Allocate an initial large row block (10e4?), then keep track of the current row, and expand as needed with additional large blocks. This method is only "slightly" more complicated. :-)

**Method 1:**
This is the table format that matches your request. It creates a dataset (table) for each `gene_pair` name. The dataset name is the name of the `gene_pair`, and it has 3 fields: Sample_ID (text), ID (extracted integer), and the test value associated to this sample.

```
with h5py.File("SO_61351577_1.h5", 'w') as h5f:
  for sample_N in sample_dict:
    for gene_pair, cor_val in sample_dict.get(sample_N).items():
        gene_dt = np.dtype ([ ('Sample', 'S20'), ('ID', int), ('Value', float) ]) 
        if gene_pair not in h5f.keys() :
            gene_pair_ds = h5f.create_dataset(gene_pair, (1,), maxshape=(None,), dtype=gene_dt,
                           compression="gzip", compression_opts=9)
        else:
            gene_pair_ds = h5f[gene_pair]
            gene_pair_ds.resize(gene_pair_ds.shape[0] + 1, axis=0)
        gene_pair_ds[-1,'Sample'] = sample_N
        gene_pair_ds[-1,'ID'] = int(sample_N[7:] )
        gene_pair_ds[-1,'Value']  = cor_val
```

**Method 2:**
This uses a different table format. It has one row of data for each sample, and test values under the matching column/field. It's just a suggestion for your consideration. It would not make sense if the number of pairs is big (say >100). Also, the table has 0.0 for values that weren't entered, so that could be a problem.
How the process works: First I get the `gene_pair` names from the sample_N dictionaries, and build a list of unique names. I use this list to create a NumPy dtype to hold all the data. Then I loop on the sample_N dictionaries, and write all gene_pair values for that sample on the same row. Mapping to field/column is done with the gene_pair name.

```
#Create a list of unique dictionary keys:
gene_list = []
for sample_N in sample_dict:
    for gene_pair in sample_dict.get(sample_N):
        if gene_pair not in gene_list:
            gene_list.append(gene_pair)
gene_list.sort()
# Create dictionary of names and formats to use for dtype
# Then use as NumPy dtype to create the dataset
dt_genetable = {'names':['Sample','ID'], 'formats':['S20', int] }
for gene_name in gene_list:
     dt_genetable['names'].append(gene_name)
     dt_genetable['formats'].append(float)

with h5py.File("SO_61351577_2.h5", 'w') as h5f:
    genetable_ds = h5f.create_dataset('GeneTable', (0,), maxshape=(None,), 
                        dtype=dt_genetable, compression="gzip", compression_opts=9)

    for sample_N in sample_dict:
        genetable_ds.resize(genetable_ds.shape[0] + 1, axis=0)
        genetable_ds[-1,'Sample'] = sample_N
        genetable_ds[-1,'ID'] = int(sample_N[7:] )
        for gene_pair, cor_val in sample_dict.get(sample_N).items():
            print (sample_N, ':', gene_pair, ':', cor_val)
            genetable_ds[-1,gene_pair]  = cor_val
```

**Method 3:**
I created this example because this dataset/table format most closely mimics your original dictionary format. It is similar to Method 2 with slightly different dtype and table. Like Method 2, it has one row of data for each sample, with 12 additional fields for the `gene_pair` name and `cor_val` values. (I assumed you always have 6 pairs.)

```
# Create dictionary of names and formats to use for dtype
# Then use as NumPy dtype to create dataset
sample_table_dt = {'names':['Sample','ID'], 'formats':['S20', int] }
for cnt in range(1,7,1):
     sample_table_dt['names'].append('gene_name_'+str(cnt))
     sample_table_dt['formats'].append('S20')
     sample_table_dt['names'].append('cor_val_'+str(cnt))
     sample_table_dt['formats'].append(float)

with h5py.File("SO_61351577_3.h5", 'w') as h5f:
    sample_table_ds = h5f.create_dataset('SampleTable', (0,), maxshape=(None,), 
                        dtype=sample_table_dt, compression="gzip", compression_opts=9)

    for sample_N in sample_dict:
        sample_table_ds.resize(sample_table_ds.shape[0] + 1, axis=0)
        sample_table_ds[-1,'Sample'] = sample_N
        sample_table_ds[-1,'ID'] = int(sample_N[7:] )
        gcnt = 1
        for gene_pair, cor_val in sample_dict.get(sample_N).items():
            sample_table_ds[-1,'gene_name_'+str(gcnt)]  = gene_pair
            sample_table_ds[-1,'cor_val_'+str(gcnt)]  = cor_val
            gcnt += 1
```

**Code to create the sample_N dictionary:**

```
sample_1 = {'gene1_gene1': 1,
            'gene1_gene2': -0.385,
            'gene1_gene3': 0.25,
            'gene2_gene2': 1,
            'gene2_gene3': 0.004,
            'gene3_gene3': 1
           }
sample_2 = {'gene1_gene1': 1,
            'gene1_gene2': -0.0035,
            'gene1_gene4': 0.0421,
            'gene2_gene2': 1,
            'gene2_gene4': -0.0783,
            'gene4_gene4': 1
           }
sample_3 = {'gene1_gene1': 1,
            'gene1_gene2': -0.065,
            'gene1_gene4': 0.0567,
            'gene2_gene2': 1,
            'gene2_gene3': -0.0378,
            'gene4_gene4': 1
           }

sample_dict = dict( sample_1=sample_1,
                    sample_2=sample_2,
                    sample_3=sample_3 )
```

Comment: kcw78, thank you very much! I'll try to use your approaches and let you some feedback later.

Also, I've already implemented another approaches:

1) 3 datasets: the first one is for gene_pair storage (N, 1), the second one is for values storage (N, M) and the third one is for sample names storage (M, 1).

2) sqlite-dict: it's a wrapper for pickle module, so I can save my data in binary format, and it also supports comression.

Comment: After posting, I realized you might want to save the sample_N data in it's original format (`Sample_ID` with 6 pairs of `gene_pair` and `cor_val`). It's easy enough to do; 
 just a slight modification to Method 2. I added as Method 3.